# PRAM CREW algorithm for counting odd numbers

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, big-o, complexity-theory

So I try to solve the following task:

Develop an CREW PRAM algorithm for counting the odd numbers of a sequence of integers x_1,x_2,...x_n.

n is the number of processors - the complexity should be O(log n) and log_2 n is a natural number

My solution so far:

```
Input: A:={x_1,x_2,...,x_n} Output:=oddCount
begin 
1. global_read(A(n),a)
2. if(a mod 2 != 0) then
       oddCount += 1
```

The problem is, due to CREW I am not allowed to use multiple write instructions at the same time `oddCount += 1` is reading oddCount and then writes `oddCount + 1`, so there would be multiple writes.

Do I have to do something like this

```
Input: A:={x_1,x_2,...,x_n} Output:=oddCount
begin 
1. global_read(A(n),a)
2. if(a mod 2 != 0) then
       global_write(1, B(n))
3. if(n = A.length - 1) then
      for i = 0 to B.length do
         oddCount += B(i)
```

So first each process determines wether it is a odd or even number and the last process calculates the sum? But how would this affect the complexity and is there a better solution?

Thanks to libik I came to this solution: (n starts with 0)

```
Input: A:={x_1,x_2,...,x_n} Output:=A(0):=number off odd numbers
begin 
1. if(A(n) mod 2 != 0) then
       A(n) = 1
   else
       A(n) = 0
2. for i = 1 to log_2(n) do
       if (n*(2^i)+2^(i-1) < A.length)
           A(n*(2^i)) += A(n*(2^i) + (2^(i-1)))
end
```

i = 1 --> A(n * 2): 0 2 4 6 8 10 ... A(n*2 + 2^0): 1 3 5 7 ...

i = 2 --> A(n * 4): 0 4 8 12 16 ... A(n*4 + 2^1): 2 6 10 14 18 ...

i = 3 --> A(n * 8): 0 8 16 24 32 ... A(n*8 + 2^2): 4 12 20 28 36 ...

So the first if is the 1st Step and the for is representing log_2(n)-1 steps so over all there are log_2(n) steps. Solution should be in A(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is O(n) as there is for cycle that has to go through all the numbers (which means you dont utilize multiple processors at all)

The CREW means you cannot write into the same cell (in your example cell=processor memory), but you can write into multiple cells at once.

So how to do it as fast as possible?

At initialization all processors start with 1 or 0 (having odd number or not)

In first round just sum the neighbours x_2 with x_1, then x_4 with x_3 etc.
It will be done in O(1) as every second processor "p_x" look to "p_x+1" processor in parallel and add 0 or 1 (is there odd number or not)

Then in processors p1,p3,p5,p7.... you have part of solution. Lets do this again but now with p1 looks to p3, p5 looks to p7 and p_x looks to o_x+2

Then you have part of the solution only in processors p1, p5, p9 etc.

Repeat the process. Every step the number of processors halves, so you need log_2(n) steps.

---

If this would be real-life example, there is often calculated cost of synchronization. Basically after each step, all processors have to synchronize themselves so they now, they can do the second step (as you run the described code in each processor, but how do you know if you can already add number from processor p_x, because you can do it after p_x finished work).

You need either some kind of "clock" or synchronization.

At this example, the final complexity would be `log(n)*k`, where `k` is the complexity of synchronization.

The cost depends on machine, or definition. One way how to notify processors that you have finished is basically the same one as the one described here for counting the odd numbers. Then it would also cost `k=log(n)` which would result in `log^2(n)`

Comment: Dubbox - I think the "indexes" of processors are not correct, instead of ```n``` you should have ```n^i```, so you get numbers "2, 4, 8, 16, 32..."

Comment: libik - I tried to achieve this by if(n mod i == 0) so in the first step, processors 0,2,4,6,.. are doing the calculation, in the second 0,3,6,9,... and so on. 
If you will do it with n^i it will propably do the same, the question is what is more efficient? guess it's yours?

Comment: you will not get correct solution, the best thing is to take the pencil and paper and draw it, image it as having n people that can give notes to each other.

You need 0,2,4,6,8... in firs step, then 0,4,8,12,16... then 0,8,16,32,64

Comment: this just got more complex than I thought but I guess i got the solution. {n^i} would have also resulted in 0 1 4 9 16. But i think my edit will do it? Is it still O(log_2 n) steps then or do i have to include the 1. into my for loop? And why is the task asking for O(log n) may that be a typo?

Comment: First step takes O(1) time (all processors do this in parallel no matter how big ```n``` is), so it does not affect anything. Solution is correct now, should take only log_2(n) steps. If you would be interested in real-life solution, there is usually also calculation of synchronization. After each step in for-loop processor must notify others that they have "finished" so next step can be made. The time for synchronization depends on a concrete machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163347/discussion-between-dubbox-and-libik).